# List documents stored in iBooks

Tags: ios, ibooks

How would I be able to list all of the books in iBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  It is an issue with security; I download an app and find out it records all of the titles of all of the books I bought...

Comment: +1: @Tibi probably works for the FBI and wants to keep track of all our books.